# In/on - which do we use talking about episodes or seasons of a tv series?

Tags: prepositions

What episode does that happen **on**?
What episode does that happen **in**?

When talking about episodes or seasons of a tv series, do we use **in** or **on**?

They have the fight **on** or **in** the second episode?

Answer (score 1):

We use happen in. What you are watching is happening **within** the content, not on the content so to speak. So to be correct, ask what episode the event occurred in, rather than on.